# How to load SharedService in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have created a shared service in order to store global information in my app:

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    GLOBAL_WIDTH = 300;
    USER_PROFILE : any  = {

    }
}
```

Then, I declare it in `appModule`:

```
import { SharedService} from './shared.service';
@NgModule({

  providers: [
    SharedService,

  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The next thing I want to do is to get/set data from this service. 
I currently import SharedService to each component it is required, and using the constructor I get/set info:

```
import { SharedService } from './shared.service';
...

  constructor(private sharedService : SharedService) {

        this.sharedService.USER_PROFILE = profile;

      });
    });
  }
```

And for using in another Component:

```
//Inside TopNav
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';


export class TopNav  implements OnInit{

    userProfile = this.sharedService.USER_PROFILE;
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private sharedService : SharedService) {
    }

));

    }
...
}
```

But this looks wrong to me, as if I understand correctly, I instantiate SharedService on every class I use it that way?
Also, will it be consistent?

Comment: You are doing it right. This is the way of providing global services. If you are looking to share service between only some components you can provide it at lower modules. If you want to keep it global, provide at app.module and inject at component/service constructors.

Comment: It makes a different instance on every import, doesn't it?

Comment: Your example SharedService is singleton. So, no.

Comment: no, only a different instance for every provider. If you provide it on a component one instance for every instance of this component. Providers of `@NgModule()` are all added to the root scope and if the same provider is added to several such modules then only one provider is actually added to the root scope - therefore one instance for the whole application. Lazy loaded modules have their own root scope.

Comment: Thanks! @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: And thank you @SefaÜmitOray